# How to get network drive to work in ubuntu

Tags: nfs

I have added this line to my /etc/fstab in my ubuntu environment

```
fs-abc-03.abc.mycompany.com:/vol/vol02902/drive /projects/drive nfs intr,nolock 0 0
```

but after I reboot and I 'cd /projects/drive', it said 'path not found'.

What else I need to do/trouble shoot this problem?

Comment: What error message, if any, do you receive when you do `sudo mount /projects/drive` ?

Comment: It said 'mount.nfs: mount point /projects/drive does not exist'

Comment: Ah, then do `sudo mkdir -p /projects/drive` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The mountpoint (`/projects/drive`) needs to exist before the NFS mount can
succeed.  So make sure you create it with

```
 sudo mkdir -p /projects/drive
```

Once the mountpoint exists, you can test the mount, to see if you get any displayed
error messages (such as the remote server denying mount access, or you have some
configuration typo in your `/etc/fstab`):

```
 sudo mount /projects/drive
```

If that works, then you should be all set for the next reboot to mount it
automatically.